# How to show/display images in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

I am trying to display the images of my Houses from the folder but it shows the error like this

> http://localhost/jageerx/assets/images/House/assets/images/House28278954_957081961107785_391331158313648576_n.jpg
>
> > 404 (Not Found)

My code is below

```
<?php
$PropertyType = "";
$image = "";
if($data != null)
{
foreach($data as $key=>$value)
{
    $PropertyType = $value['PropertyType'];
    $image=$value['HouseImage1'];
}
}
?>
```

the front-end code is this

```
 <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/House/'. $image);?>" alt="tab1" class="img img-responsive">
```

folders hierarchy is mentioned below

[image: This is the hierarchy of folders]

this is the model function

```
public function SIngleHouseADD($houseID)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('housedetail');
    $this->db->where('HouseID', $houseID);
    //$qry = $qry->result_array();
    $query=$this->db->get();
    $resultArray = $query->result_array();
    return $resultArray;
    //return $qry;
}
```

this one is the controller

```
public function SingleProperty()
{
    //$HouseID = $_GET['id'];
    $this->load->model('SingleAddModel');
    $plots = $this->SingleAddModel->SIngleHouseADD($_GET['id']);
    $data = array();
    $data["data"] = $plots;
    $this->load->view('SinglePropertyDetail_view', $data);
}
```

Comment: Well you're somehow building your path wrong. It seems `$image` contains a duplicate reference to `assets/images/House`.

Comment: Thanks for your kind response but sir "assets/images/House" this is the path where image is present.

Comment: Yes but you have `assets/images/House` TWICE - look at the generated path.

Comment: img should be inside foreach loop

Comment: yes image is in foreach loop

Comment: then show your fulll code not chunk

Comment: ok thanks Utkanos but what i will do

Comment: @pradeep sir me update the code

Comment: What value do you assign `$config['base_url']` in config.php?

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/jageerx/';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base_url()` you are passing `assets/images/House/` the same path in `$image`, so it is duplicating path, I'll suggest you to first `echo` the results then use them in html. And for your Image you can use:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url().$image;?>" alt="tab1" class="img img-responsive">
```

OR

```
<img src="assets/images/House/<?php echo $image;?>" alt="tab1" class="img img-responsive">
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Since your `$image` variable already contains `assets/images/House`  so should not be use in `base_url()` again*

*Should be like this :*

```
 foreach($data as $key=>$value) {
        $PropertyType = $value['PropertyType'];
        $image=$value['HouseImage1'];
    ?>
        <img src="<?php echo base_url().$image;?>" alt="tab1" class="img img-responsive"> 

    <?php }?>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much sir for your effort but it gives again error like this  GET http://localhost/jageerx/assets/images/House28278954_957081961107785_391331158313648576_n.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Comment: and also `$image` variable should have `/` after the `House` should be like this `House/28278954_957081961107785_391331158313648576_n.jpg` Currently it is like this  `House28278954_957081961107785_391331158313648576_n.jpg` change it when adding to database

Comment: i think u got the idea

Comment: did u check my answer? is it helpful ?

Comment: if my answer helps you pls don't hesitate to check it as green

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this works best for you but when I add images or css in codeigniter I usually add them in the same level as my index.php so it goes like this!

See screenshot.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfk4z.jpg)